# JUnit run suite

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, junit

I wrote a maven-JUnit project that I run through Eclipse.
I have package with five classes:
1. JunitTest1.java
2. JunitTest2.java
3. Adapter.java,
4. JunitTestSuite.java
5. TestRunner.java

The code in the JunitTestSuite class is

```
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Suite;
import org.junit.runners.Suite.SuiteClasses;

@RunWith(Suite.class)
@SuiteClasses({ JunitTest1.class, JunitTest2.class })
public class JunitTestSuite  {
}
```

the code in the TestRunner class is:

```
import org.junit.runner.JUnitCore;
import org.junit.runner.Result;
import org.junit.runner.notification.Failure;

public class TestRunner {

public static void main(String[] args) {

  Result result = JUnitCore.runClasses(JunitTestSuite.class);

  for (Failure failure : result.getFailures()) {
     System.out.println(failure.toString());
  }
  System.out.println(result.wasSuccessful());
   }  
 }
```

When I run the project as Junit Test, there are 4 test running, the two tests under the suite and each of the tests separately; meaning that each test is ran twice. Any suggestions how to run only the suite?
thanks!
Orit

Comment: Why do you have TestRunner and JunitTestSuite? It's enough having simply JunitATest.java and JUnitBTest.java.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using maven you don't need TestRunner class. you can introduce your suite class to maven in your pom.xml like this:

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.17</version>
                <configuration>
                    <argLine>-Xmx3g</argLine>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/JunitTestSuite.java</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

it will run you suite class and your test classes will not run twice.

Comment: Will it work even if I don't use eclipse to run it in  the future?

Comment: yes. I'm not using eclipse but this config is still working for me. It's maven configuration it doesn't care about your IDE. you can even run test with "mvn test" command and it will work. If you don't want to use maven you can just right click on your SuiteClass and run it as JUnit.